# Pushwoosh send notification to everybody except some users

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, pushwoosh

Is there a way to send notification to everybody except some users ?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide your approach first, and be more specific and share your code blocks what your have tried about your question.

Comment: I believe my question is simple. Pushwoosh provide a tags system that you can use to notify only tags devices . I want to exclude some tags ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A("00000-00000") \ T("userId", IN, "[1,2,3]")
```

All devices subscribed to the `app 00000-00000` which don't have the `userId` in `[1,2,3]` set.

I created this filter according to [Advanced Tags Guide.](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/advanced-tags-guide/) So you can give your userId's in array set which you don't want to send. Or you can try vice versa, give IN only to targeted users' ids.

Comment: How do i do this using the CreateMessage API ?

Comment: You will populate this tag's array, and in json `"filter="A(\"00000-00000\") \ T(\"userId\", IN, \"[1,2,3]\")"` attribute you can put your tag. There is an example here https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/#PushserviceAPI-Method-messages-create

Comment: Alright so i must use filters instead of conditions ? Is there a way to convert filter into conditions ?

Comment: According to docs, condition seems like more general than filters. So in this situation filter is a good choice for flexibility, may be you can convert your condition in filter.